# Bootstrap datepicker directive for angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, datepicker

I have written a simple datepicker directive. Here is the code :

```
appDirective.directive('datePicker', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: ['ngModel'],
        scope: {
            ngModel: '='
        },
        replace: true,
        template:
            '<div class="input-group">'     +
                    '<input type="text"  class="form-control" ngModel required>' +
                    '<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>' +
            '</div>' ,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var input = element.find('input');
            var nowTemp = new Date();
            var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(),0,0,0,0);
            console.log(now);
            console.log(nowTemp);

            input.datepicker({
               format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
                onRender: function(date) {
                    return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
                }
            });

            element.bind('blur keyup change', function() {
                scope.ngModel = input.val();
                console.info('date-picker event', input.val(), scope.ngModel);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

This triggers the datepicker if I use `<date-picker></date-picker>` in `html`.

However in the above directive the callback for `onRender`  doesn't work. I am using the same example as [Disable bootstrap dates](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/)

What am I doing wrong here ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onRender` function isn't a callback, its an event that is fired.  The example they use in the docs you referenced is:

```
$('#dp5').datepicker()
  .on('changeDate', function(ev){
    if (ev.date.valueOf() < startDate.valueOf()){
       ....
    }
});
```

So you should be adding an event listener, rather than supplying a callback function.  Do something like this:

```
input.datepicker()
  .on('onRender', function(ev, date){
      return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
});
```

The docs are a little fuzzy as to what exactly is passed along as part of the `'onRender'` event, but i'm pretty sure that should work.  If you aren't passed the date object, you might have to read it from the input before formatting it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a working native implementation in [AngularStrap](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap) for Bootstrap3 that leverages `ngAnimate` from AngularJS v1.2+

- Demo : http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/##datepicker

You may also want to checkout:

- Source : https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/blob/master/src/datepicker/datepicker.js

If you prefer to keep relying on TwitterBootstrap javascript, there is the old version that just does that:

- Old docs: http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/1.0/#/datepicker